Buliding weight function with vertex source to run an effiencent algorithm on directed graph with weighted vertices and edges.
The question : Let  = (,) be a directed weighted graph with a non-negative weight function : ∪  → ℝ both on the edges and the vertices. The weights are non-negative. The weight of a
path $$  = {,_1,…,_, } $$ is the sum of the weight of its edges and its vertices, not including
the first and last vertices,  and . Given  = (,,), and  ∈  , suggest an algorithm that
computes the shortest path from  to any other vertex  ∈ .
I thought to build new graph  ' = (' = { ∈ } ,' = {e ∈ }) and for every $$ a',b', s'∈ E' $$ the non-negative weight function ':E → ℝ which applies :
$$   
w'((a',b')) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{w((a,b)) + w(a),} &\quad\text{if s' ≠ a'}_\text{}\, \text{ }_\text{}\ \\
       \text{w((a,b))} &\quad\text{if s' = a'}_\text{}\ \\
       \text{} &\quad\text{}_\text{}\
       \text{} &\quad\text{} \\ 
     \end{cases}
 $$
Then, runs Dijkstra on s' and that's it.
I think that it's incorrect to approach weight function with vertex source, but I don't understand why, I would like to have an explanation about it.
In addition, I understand that there is no specific template to prove an algorithm's correctness using reduction. If this idea is correct, is it sufficient to prove correctness with the following steps?

We need to show there’s a one-to-one correspondence with the original graph

Explain why we can use the chosen algorithm (that we've written) and how we extract the output.



Why do you think it's incorrect?

Because I've never seen a weight function that relies on a vertex with a specific character (the source vertex), and I've searched for many solution examples. I assume from your comment that the idea might be correct. @MathieuRundström
